# What is an example of a positive algebraic number lacking a prime-rational factorization?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

By a prime-rational factorization of a real number $x$, let us mean a pair of finite sequences $p$ and $q$ of equal length such that every $p_i$ is a prime number, every $q_i$ is a non-zero rational number (possibly negative), and $x = \prod_i p_i^{q_i}.$

> **Q.** What is an example of a positive algebraic number lacking a prime-rational factorization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exercise you should attempt: A number has a "prime-rational factorization" if and only if it is an $n$th root of a positive rational number for some natural number $n$.

There are of course algebraic numbers not of this form. One can use nested radicals, or even take algebraic numbers that *cannot* be expressed using radicals, e.g. a positive root of $x^5=x+1$.